# Importing test scripts into a django testrunner

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

I have a test runner in a django package that is split across two directories, like so:

```
package/models.py
package/tests/__init__.py
package/tests/test_foo.py
package/contrib/bar/models.py
package/contrib/bar/tests/__init__.py
package/contrib/bar/tests/test_bar.py
```

In `package/tests/__init__.py` I have this:

```
from package.contrib.tests import test_bar
```

And can run this just fine:

```
./manage.py test package.tests.test_bar
```

However, if I run either of these:

```
./manage.py test package
./manage.py test package.tests
```

`test_bar` isn't run.

I've confirmed this by writing a test that will always fail and when run with either of the above calls the tests work.

Is there a way to import a test_suite into another test suite?

Comment: Have you tried importing `*`? `from package.contrib.tests.test_bar import *`?

Comment: @v1k45 That worked, but I'm seeking other answers too. But if nothing else comes up you should make that an answer so I can accept (or at least upvote) it.

Answer (score 2):

In order to run tests from `contrib` package using

```
$ ./manage.py test package.tests
```

You must import `*` from contrib tests in your `tests` package's `__init__.py`.

Like this:

```
from package.contrib.tests.tests_bar import *
from .test_foo import *
```

This will run all `contrib` tests even if you pass `package.tests` as CLI argument.

But you wont be able to specify to run only `contrib.test_bar` as `package.tests.test_bar`. To do that, simply import `test_bar` module in the `__init__.py` file too.

Comment: I've tried the latter `import test_bar` but it doesn't seem to get picked up by the test runner. The rest worked though. Thanks :)

Comment: It worked for me. You sure that you imported it same as you did in the question?

Comment: Note to readers: this used to be the accepted answer, until OP ragequit and attempted to punish bystanders for their [political disagreement with Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342994) in the process. Feel free to throw it an upvote to compensate if you like ;-)